# Why I can't order position of some div to the top of another div in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a navigation on top of slideshow as below code 
[image]

***Here is the website which I'm currently doing on it***

http://khmerlottery.biz/
I have alot of CSS and HTML So I post it into pastbin as below link 
**HTML**
http://www.n00bunlimited.net/pastebin.php?show=64443

**CSS**
http://www.n00bunlimited.net/pastebin.php?show=64441

***And This is that website which I'm current doing on it***
There is my code in Chrome developer mode I don't think both of div have it children or parent

[image]

Comment: I can't make any sense of what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok general advice

**1st :** the 2 divs sometimes *(should be in a same level (not parent/not child))* .. so maybe div not going in front has a parent with z-index less than the already front one

**2nd:** if both are absolute or fixed use z-index:  to control them

**3rd:** if one is absolute/fixed  set position to another one to be relative and z-index for it

**4th:** No need to tag jquery , javascript cause its css problem .. unless you use jquery/javascript to add css {positions and z-index}

in your website the problem with

.well-lg and .well  you set them `overflow:hidden` ?? remove `overflow:hidden` from both

Comment: Please check on my update on new images becuase I have not any parent or children on my HTMl code

Comment: @HengSopheak yes I got the image but I said its in general .. I think its better to make [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) cause with html and css we just try to imagine what is going on

Comment: This is my website which I'm current do with this cause
http://khmerlottery.biz/

Comment: You can check it http://jsfiddle.net/5nnmengn/

Comment: @HengSopheak updated answer  with your problem solution

Comment: I've disable it but it still the same

Comment: Oh now I found my miss z-index on my .container selector. 
Oh my god this is my messy code lettter I will prepare it

Thanks

Comment: @HengSopheak glad your code works .. Very Good Luck :)